# Check if Numpy Array is Stored in Shared Memory

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, shared-memory, sysv

In Python 3.8+, is it possible to check whether a numpy array is being stored in shared memory?

In the following example, a numpy array `sharedArr` was created using the buffer of a `multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory` object. Will like to know if we can write a function that can detect whether `SharedMemory` is used.

```py
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import shared_memory

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Created numpy array `sharedArr`in shared memory
    arr = np.zeros(5)
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=arr.nbytes)
    sharedArr = np.ndarray(arr.shape, dtype=arr.dtype, buffer=shm.buf)
    sharedArr[:] = arr[:]

    # How to tell if numpy array is stored in shared memory?
    print(type(sharedArr))      # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
    print(hex(id(sharedArr)))   # 0x7fac99469f30

    shm.close()
    shm.unlink()
```

Comment: `hex(id(...))` is a huge red herring. It not a useful way to determine what is going on with underyling buffers. `id` does *not* provide the memory address, that is a CPython implementation detail, it is merely a number that is guaranteed unique for the lifetime of an object. In this case, it is the address of the PyObject header of the `np.ndarray` object, but that has nothing to do with the buffer, indeed, you can create an arbitrary number of `numpy.ndarray` objects with different `id`'s that share the same buffer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this particular case, you can use the `base` attribute of the shared array. The [attribute](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.base.html?highlight=base#numpy.ndarray.base) is a reference to the underlying object from which this array derives its memory. This is `None` for most arrays, to indicate that such an array owns its data. Running this code on my machine indicates that this array's base is a `mmap` object:

```py
>>> sharedArr.base
<mmap.mmap at 0x11a4aa670>
```

If you still have a reference to the shared memory object from which the array was allocated, you can compare the array's base to the shared memory segment's memory map:

```py
>>> sharedArr.base is shm._mmap
True
```

If you *don't* have the `shm` object lying around, as you wouldn't in a standalone function which could hypothetically perform this task, I doubt there's a portable and foolproof way to do it.

Since NumPy provides its own [memory-map object](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html?highlight=memmap#numpy.memmap), it may suffice for your case to do the former check. That is, make the assumption that if the array is backed by a vanilla, builtin Python memory map, it is allocated from shared memory:

```py
import mmap

def array_is_from_shared_memory(arr):
    return isinstance(arr.base, mmap.mmap)
```

This works in your particular example, but you'd have to be careful with it, *clearly* document the assumptions that it makes, and test that it provides you with the actual information you need in your exact application.

Comment: Amazing answer, thank you! What are some examples of objects that are not backed by `mmap` but are still held in shared memory?

Comment: I'm glad you found the answer helpful! What can go wrong depends entirely on what you're doing with these arrays. If that assumption doesn't hold, there are two cases. Consider an array backed by shared memory _doesn't_ use a `mmap` under the hood. Then this function would cause you to "miss" this array in whatever code you want to run on shared arrays. OTOH, an array that _does_ use a `mmap` but isn't _actually_ shared might cause you to inadvertently overwrite some data, or to expect that change to show up somewhere else, even though it won't. How "bad" those are depends on your use case :)

Comment: This does not work. If `a` is a NumPy array, then `b = a; b.base is None` returns `True`. The `.base` attribute is only used if the array is a view over another array.

Comment: @CrisLuengo It's true that `b.base is None` in that case, but that's not the same thing as the original question. "Normal" assignment, `sharedArr = arr`, was not used to create the array, it was the `ndarray` constructor that specifically sets the buffer for `sharedArr` to be the shared memory segment. Also, the expression `sharedArr[:] = arr[:]` was used to copy data. That doesn't rebind the variable `sharedArr`, it literally copies the elements.

Comment: Sure, it’s not the context of the question. Still, your first paragraph makes it sound like `base` always points to the original array, but it doesn’t. I thought it would be important to clarify that for future visitors, hence my comment (I came here through a search for shared data in general).

Comment: Ah I see, I interpreted “does not work” as “does not solve the question”! Yes, the base attribute is only non-None in cases where the array takes its memory from “something else”. It’s a bit fraught in general, which I hopefully made clear in my answer.